# For Loop VBA - Runtime error'91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

So I am trying to just rearrange some messy data on another sheet and I can't figure out why I keep getting a "Runtime error'91': Object variable or With block variable not set" when i hit the for i = 2 to 73 line.  Thoughts?

```
  Sub dostuff()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
i = 2
sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To 73
    Cells(i, 2).Copy Destination = sht1.Cells(i, 1)
    Cells(i, 5).Copy Destination = sht1.Cells(i, 2)
    j = 1
    For j = 1 To Range("Y" & i).Value2
        Worksheets("Time Log").Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 2)).Copy Destination = sht1.Cells(i, 3)
        Worksheets("Time Log").Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 3)).Copy Destination = sht1.Cells(i, 4)
        Worksheets("Time Log").Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 5)).Copy Destination = sht1.Cells(i, 5)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please qualify `Cells(i, 2)` with a sheet. Edit: if you don't need formatting, just set the cells to each other.

Comment: `Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Side note: there is no need to assign values to `i` or `j` before the loops

Comment: Ok, you're right....not sure how I missed that "set"            but now im getting an error on the destination for the copy :( seems like I can't code today

Comment: `Destination :=` not `Destination =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 91 is asking you to create a with block:

```
Sub dostuff()

Dim i%, j%, endLoop%
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
'i = 2 not necessary

set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set was missing

With sht1 'with block
    For i = 2 To 73
        Cells(i, 2).Copy .Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(i, 5).Copy .Cells(i, 2)
        j = 1 'not necessary
        endLoop = Range("Y" & i).Value2 'so you don't have to evaluate it each iteration
        For j = 1 To endLoop
            Worksheets("Time Log").Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 2)).Copy .Cells(i, 3)
            Worksheets("Time Log").Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 3)).Copy .Cells(i, 4)
            Worksheets("Time Log").Cells(i, ((j * 4) + 5)).Copy .Cells(i, 5)
        Next j
    Next i
End with 'close with block

End Sub
```